# SMACC or any other state machine for ROS2

Tags: ros, ros2, state

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. Does anybody know when [SMACC](https://smacc.dev) will be available for ROS2?
2. Are there any other state machine libraries for ROS2 (preferably written in C++)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/384618/smacc-or-any-other-state-machine-for-ros2/) by [Artem](https://answers.ros.org/users/5031/artem/) on ROS Answers with karma: 709 on 2021-08-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> 1. Does anybody know when SMACC will be available for ROS2?

https://github.com/robosoft-ai/SMACC2/tree/foxy

> 2. Are there any other state machine libraries for ROS2 (preferably written in C++)?

Yes, SMACH and It is also available for ros2.

https://github.com/lesire/executive_smach/tree/ros2-eloquent

---

Originally posted by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) with karma: 1622 on 2021-08-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [leuko](https://answers.ros.org/users/57019/leuko/) on 2022-02-08**:
For ROS2 foxy: According to https://github.com/ros/executive_smach/issues/70#issuecomment-981311141 there is a foxy fork of SMACH which I personally did not try:

- https://github.com/DeepX-inc/executive_smach
- https://github.com/DeepX-inc/executive_smach_visualization